# Changing size of MainWindow.xib's Window

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Is there a way to change the dimensions of the main window in Xcode, the `Window` object stored in the `MainWindow.xib` from an iphone size to an iPad size? Other dimensions are editable of other nib file objects, like views, etc, but the main Window appears to not be.

If it cannot be changed, then I guess I would need to create a new nib window nib file for the iPad device family, and then manually add the viewcontroller and other information into it, is this the only option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just right click on the target and select Duplicate.  A dialog box will show up, select Duplicate and Transition to iPad.  Then all you need to do is select which scheme you want to build for, iPad or iPhone.  This way Xcode will duplicate all the needed xib files in your project and you will not have to manually add the needed view controllers.

To choose the scheme, select the left side of the bar that says iPhone 4.3 Simulator.  Select the one with copy at the end and you should be good to go.

Comment: nice option, thanks. But really, what i need is to just change this one particular file.

Comment: okay i decided to use the duplicate option, which creates a new iPad MainWindow.xib. However even when removing the old MainWindow.xib (I just renamed it) the app is still running in iPhone mode, even though the new Windows size is the iPad dimensions in MainWindow.xib. Why would this be?

Comment: I see.  You can also create a Universal app which will allow one app to run on multiple devices.  Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767393/xcode-how-to-make-a-universal-app

Comment: Did you select the correct scheme?  I have updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I know about Universal apps. I want to know how can I get the app to use the new converted iPad version of MainWindow.xib instead of the old one?

Comment: It is still won't run the iPad version even after you changed the scheme?

Comment: I duplicated the target and got a new MainWindow.xib which has an iPad-sized window. I removed the old MainWindow.xib. However, when I run this on the ipad, the window is still the iphone size (with the 2x button on the ipad).

Comment: apparently, the plist entry for `main nib file base name` doesn't seem to do anything? I can remove it or give a bogus name, and it is still latching onto my iphone version of MainWindow.xib

Comment: Which route did you go with Universal or Duplicate and Transition to iPad?  If you went with Duplicate and Transition to iPad, Did you change the scheme?  Every time you want to build for the iPhone or iPad you are going to have to change between the schemes.  Also I should mention if you want to go Universal, there is a Devices popup button in the summary tab of your project that will also allow you to transition your app.  Sorry if this is confusing, I just want to give you all the options.

Comment: I got it working, thanks! i wasn't changing the scheme, left that part out of the process. Cheers and thanks for all the help!